# Trying to understand Picard's theorem on existence and uniqueness

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the theorem states that if $f$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$ are continous on some rectangle $xy$ centre of $(x_0,y_0)$ then the initial value problem $\frac{df}{dx}=f(x,y)$ with $y(x_0)=y_0$, has a unique solution which is continuous on at least $|x-x_0| \lt h$ where $h \gt 0$

So here is an image of $\frac{df}{dx}=2x$ and $y=x^2$

[image]

Now the solutions for $\frac{df}{dx}=2x$ are actually $y=x^2+C$. Now my understanding is that for intital conditions $f(0)=0,f(2)=4$ the $C=0$ because in the diagram this is where the two intersect. On all other regions we need a C because $f(x_0)=y_0$ can only be true with a constant factoring in to make up the difference between the two graphs? And the constant would be precisely this value. For example, at a point $x=1.5,y=2.25$, I can work out the $C$ by $1.5*2-1.5^2=0.75$ because $y=2.25+0.75=3$. Of course in reality I would not work out this way, but this is just for illustration to see if I am understanding the theorem.

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prescribe $f(0)$ *and* $f(2)$, the solution is already uniquely determined by either of these.

Apart from that, if you know the solution is of the form $f(x)=x^2 + C$ for some constant $C$ then and an initial $b$ value at, say $a$, is prescribed, then $f(a)= a^2 + C = b$, so $C=b-a^2$ can be easily deduced. I don't understand what you want to do with the intersection of the graphs.

Comment: I realize that in practice working out $C$ would be done exactly as you have described. The idea with the graphs is to help visualize a rectangle center of $(x_0,y_0)$ and to see if I have understood what Picard is saying.